# jquery get document width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im running in to a weird issue with getting the width of the document. Im using `$(document).width()` to get the width both on `$(window).load` and `$(window).resize`, my problem occurs when the browser is open full screen then resized (shrank) to a width where the content requires you to scroll horizontally to see all the content. At the point in which you need to scroll my header and footer divs  just end. I would like them to go 100% of the document width. The problem fixes itself when i refresh the page. Is there a solution that allows a browser to shrink when resizing the window and updates the header and footer divs? This is what i have so far and its not working.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    resize_me();
});
$(window).resize(function() {
    resize_me();
});
function resize_me() {
    var doc_width = $(document).width();
    $('#header').width(doc_width);
    $('#footer').width(doc_width);
    console.log(doc_width);
}
```

Comment: Here is an example of what im experiencing. maximize your browser then shrink it so its less then 700px wide. Once the window is shrank scroll horizontally to the right and you will see that the read div with width: 100% is only 100% of the window...not the document. http://pastebin.com/s45pZRWd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `window.innerWidth`, it should get you the size of the viewport.

No jQuery needed.

and honestly, why not just set their widths to `100%` with css ???

```
#header, #footer {
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. Some browsers dont continue the background color of the div when you have to scroll to the right to see the rest of the content. Im at a loss as what to do. I may try using a background image and re-peating it to see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are saying correctly you could try the following in your stylesheet, which would be much more efficient than using JS.

```
#header, #footer{
    width : 100%;
}
```